# Do you always need HTML5 Boilerplate or HTML5 Reset?

Tags: html

Most HTML5 tutorials doesn't mention the need for "resetting" HTML5 for browser compatibility and they basically just teach the new elements like `header` `footer` etc... Then there are things like http://html5boilerplate.com/ and http://html5reset.org/ which appears to advocate maximum browser compatibility.

My question is, do we always need any of these if we plan to make HTML5 websites? Is it a prerequisite or are we gonna be just fine without it?

I ask because HTML5 boilerplate appears to add a lot of code including several `if` statements, modernizr, jquery, even Google Analytics, etc., as part of the default package.

Comment: If you don't need to support IE less than 9, don't bother. Older versions of other browsers support HTML5 elements pretty well, although CSS3 not so much.

Comment: The thing to remember is that no amount of CSS will make older browsers handle HTML5 elements like `audio` well. So in that regard, you will have to choose between doing HTML5 or supporting older browsers. But hey, some simple CSS like `header, footer, article, section, hgroup {display:block}` won't do any harm.

Comment: @MrLister Is it safe to say that if I only intend to use `header, footer, article, section, hgroup` and not the other "advance" elements, I don't need HTML5 Boilerplate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it a prerequisite

No, it isn't. The Internet police will not come after you if you don't use either one.

But having those is a good idea if you develop sites that would be used in multiple browsers and older ones to boot.

Comment: Just add that we don't have to bother with html5boilerplate. HTML5Shiv + YUI reset are, for example, more than sufficient.

Comment: @Pierre Interesting. At what point do you think html5boilerplate is needed?

Comment: Well. I think html5boilerplate is not *needed*, at all. But, that said, if you need jQuery, Modernizr, and see a point in using their .htaccess, you may seriously consider using it.